# I-adjective with -き, what does it mean?

Tags: grammar

Under which circumstances 楽しい can turn into 楽しき?

Comment: Related:https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/how-does-ki-form-of-i-adjectives-work-e-g-%E6%84%9B%E3%81%97%E3%81%8D

Comment: This pretty much answers my question I guess.