# I cannot understand sentences in this paragraph

Tags: grammar

here:

> 感動は、自分の力だけでなく、親の力だったり、友だちの力だったり、ほかの人の力によってもつくられています。子どものときから大事に育てられたとか、**自分を包んでくれる街がきちっと大人たちによって美しく保たれていたとか**、そういう周囲の力でつくられている場合もあるわけです。
> そうした感動の思い出を大切に持ち帰ってきて、いまあるものとコラボレーションする（注2）と、新商品が生まれます。そういう意味では、まるっきりの（注3）新商品なんてあり得ません。アイディアはいつも、そんな過去の「感動の森」の中から探し出してくるものなのです。
> いい思い出がたくさんあるかどうか、いい人に会ったかどうか、美味しいものを食べたかどうか。**そういうヒト·コト·モノとのよき思い出の引き出しをどれだけ持っているかによって**、アイディアの湧き出る（注4）量は変わるのです

the sentence "自分を包んでくれる街がきちっと大人たちによって美しく保たれていたとか" makes no sense to me if it is translated as "street that wrapped you is protected by adults",maybe the part 自分を包んでくれる is a metaphor?

"よき" in the sentence "そういうヒト·コト·モノとの**よき**思い出の引き出しをどれだけ持っているかによって" is also not understandable,maybe this is a typo?

Comment: You should consider splitting this into two questions.

Answer (score 1):

良き is the 連体形 of the adjective 良し in Classical Japanese, which is the form that's used to modify a noun. It is the origin of the modern adjective 良い.

While this particular way of conjugating verbs no longer exists in the modern language, 良き is still fossilised in expressions like よき思い出 or 古き良き時代 to yield a sense of nostalgia.

Answer (score 1):

- 街 means *town* or *city*, not *street*. I'm not sure what is the best verb for this 包む, but you may use *embrace*, *surround*, etc. Here it basically refers to the environment bigger than your family or school.
- よき is a stilted and old-sounding variant of the attributive form of よい. See: [How does -ki form of i-adjectives work? (e.g. 愛しき)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3120/5010)

Comment: For referring to a physical environment, *surround* is natural in English (and *embrace* is definitely not). As a noun, *surroundings* is often offered as a synonym for *environment*. However, at least to me it seems awkward to speak of a town *that surrounds* you. One might instead talk about the town *around* you.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you. I know that's the normal way to say it, but 包んでくれる is a bit of a figurative expression (sounds like some great being is protecting you), so I was curious if there was a fancy expression for it.